# PDO leaving .laccdb file behind

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo

I'm using PDO on Windows 7 with PHP 5.6.30 to copy an empty MS Access .accdb file (PDO can't create Access files from nothing) and populate it.  When the script is done, the .accdb file is accompanied by a .laccdb record lock file, which will normally disappear once a connection to an .accdb file is closed.  I'm ending my PHP script by setting the PDO connection to `null`, so I'm wondering whether there's something else I can/should do to allow the .laccdb file to lapse.  This isn't really critical, I'm just trying to determine why it's happening and if I can change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I determined that the problem was a lack of Delete permissions for the folder.  I thought I had enabled that permission, so this is kind of a no-brainer.